# Prove that $a^7 + b^7 + c^7 \geq a^4b^3 + b^4c^3 + c^4a^3$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

> Prove that $a^7 + b^7 + c^7 \geq a^4b^3 + b^4c^3 + c^4a^3$

Values $a,b,c$ are all positive reals. I tried Muirhead and a few AM $\geq$ GM.

This problem is equivalent to proving $a^4b^3 + b^4c^3 + c^4a^3 \geq c^2a^5 + b^2c^5+a^2b^5$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inequality does not change if $(a, b, c)$ are permuted
cyclically, therefore we can assume
that $a \le b \le c$ or $a \ge b \ge c$.

In the *first case* $a \le b \le c$ we can
apply the [Rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) to
$$
x_1 = a^4, x_2 = b^4, x_3 = c^4 \\ y_1 = a^3, y_2 = b^3, y_3 = c^3 \, .
$$
The rearrangement inequality states that
$$
x_1y_2 + x_2y_3 + x_3y_1 \le 
x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 
$$
which is exactly the desired inequality.

In the *second case* $a \ge b \ge c$ we can do the same with
$$
x_1 = c^3, x_2 = b^3, x_3 = a^3 \\ y_1 = c^4, y_2 = b^4, y_3 = a^4 \, .
$$

Comment: even if $a \leq b \leq c$ I still can't afirm nothing about $(a^3,b^3,c^3)$ or $(a^4,b^4,c^4)$ once they can be greater or smaller than 1

Comment: @onlyme: $a \le b \le c$ implies $a^3 \le b^3 \le c^3$ and $a^4 \le b^4 \le c^4$.

Comment: The inequality is not symmetric, so you can't assume wlog $a\le b\le c$.

Comment: @user26486: Good point, thanks. – I have edited the answer, hopefully OK now.

Comment: Nice +1.  Note that all you need is that $(a^4, b^4, c^4)$ and $(a^3, b^3, c^3)$ are both similarly ordered, which is true for non-negatives.

Answer (score 6):

Earth lended me it's energy. Without any assumption on the size of $a,b,c$:

$a^7 + a^7 + a^7 + a^7 + b^7 + b^7 + b^7 \geq 7a^4b^3$

$b^7 + b^7 + b^7 + b^7 + c^7 + c^7 + c^7 \geq 7b^4c^3$

$c^7 + c^7 + c^7 + c^7 + a^7 + a^7 + a^7 \geq 7c^4a^3$

adding up I get what I wanted

Comment: If $a,b\in(0,1)$, then are you sure that your first inequality holds?

Comment: Arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.